# Can I Leverage Azure cognitive search with/inside power BI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I am able to find enough blog/posts on how to use Power BI to analyze Azure cognitive search data.  But what I am looking is exactly opposite of this.

Can we use **Azure cognitive search inside/for power BI reports** to query on power BI data? Basically a search bar in power BI or anywhere in app that can do the following : -

1. Query on Power BI data sources and return visualization.
   for example :- top 5 hotels by people visited result in relevant visualization.
2. smart enough like Azure cognitive search to understand human search errors.

FYI I have already explored **QnA** visualization of power BI, but I still want to explore the possibility of leverage Azure cognitive search instead of that.

I have my data stored in **sql server in Azure VM** and **Azure blob storage**.

is it possible? if yes can someone please share relevant links/videos to help me accomplish that.

Comment: Did you happen to check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-tutorial-use-cognitive-services

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search) can send operation logs and service metrics to an Azure Storage account, which you can then visualize in Power BI.
Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-monitor-logs-powerbi) for detail description.

Power BI provides access to a set of functions from **Azure Cognitive Services** to enrich your data in the self-service data prep for Dataflows. The services that are supported today are **Sentiment Analysis**, **Key Phrase Extraction**, **Language Detection**, and I**mage Tagging**.

These options are running based on the power of Azure Cognitive Services. These Azure services are leveraged within Power BI by a few simple clicks.
For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-tutorial-use-cognitive-services).

You can build the  Power BI solution with Azure Cognitive Services, without using the  **Power BI Premium** for more details refer this [document](https://data-marc.com/2020/05/04/leverage-azure-cognitive-services-in-power-bi-without-premium-subscription/)